Memory allocation issue caused by ABI compatibility problem for dynamic proto library
I got a problem about memory allocation when I test ABI compatibility of dynamic proto library.
What version of protobuf and what language are you using?
Version: v3.19.6
Language: C++
What operating system (Linux, Windows, ...) and version?
Linux Ubuntu 20.04.6
What runtime / compiler are you using (e.g., python version or gcc version)
gcc 9.4.0
What did you do?
I make a program to test ABI compatibility of proto dynamic library.
This program is constructed with MessageClass(which is defined by proto), Class1, Class2, some communication class and entry main. In this program, I make Class1 object to create a MessageClass object and transform to Class2 object.
The MessageClass consists of two fields, version and message, both of which are of type string.
I make three dynamic libraries for Class1, Class2 and MessageClass. Class1 and Class2 depends on MessageClass.
When I run the program as usual, there is no problem. However, the following are the actions that cause the problem:

Build the program and copy Class1 library for backup.
Add a test field at the last of MessageClass in *.proto file(its field number is larger than other field), and then build the program without modifying other parts.
Replace new Class1 library with backup library.
Run program.

What did you expect to see
I think it should run as if I have not replaced Class1 library.
What did you see instead?
A coredump happened. It shows malloc(): invalid size (unsorted) when running the code defined in Class1.
Anything else we should know about your project / environment
I use bazel 6.5.0 in this program, and use cc_shared_library wrapped with cc_import to build and dynamically link these dynamic libraries.
We use gdb to find error location, and find that errors may occur in different positions, but they must occur during memory allocation. When I define an additional std::string object with over 16 length in member function of Class1 , or set message field of MessageClass object, it will crash when allocate more memory. However, the program is little enough and do not need much memory.
I tried to define a MessageClass in usual way instead of using proto, and performed the above actions that may result in errors. The program runs normally. So I think it may be a feature or bug of dynamic proto library which limits memory allocation.
Here is a minimal reproducible example of your program.
void Class1::Run() {
  std::shared_ptr<ProtoMessage> message_shared_ptr = std::make_shared<ProtoMessage>();
  ProtoMessage* message_ptr = message_shared_ptr.get();
  std::string message = "";  // If we write message = message_ptr->message() in this line, a malloc error will be reported when google_protobuf allocate some memory for 'message' field in this line.
  std::string version = "Ve";
  std::string addition = "Class1Object" + version;  // If we write version = "Version1" above, a malloc error will be reported in this line cause 'addition' is too long and need more memory.
  message += addition;
  message_ptr->set_message(message);  // If there is no error above, this line will report a malloc error. 'message' is a field of ProtoMessage class.
  // ...
}


Please don't describe your code, show it. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] of your program. Add a comment on the line in your code where the crash happens.

Looks like you are misusing protobuf. Classes generated by protobuf should not be part of public API of library (doesn't matter which language you are using). Protobuf purpose is to internalize and externalize data into binary format which is easy to maintain, so for example two parties (written in different programing languages) can communicate over the network. If you have problem with ABI, you are using protobuf in wrong context.


I think it should run as if I have not replaced Class1 library.

Your expectation is simply wrong. Adding fields to a protocol buffers message changes the C++ class definition.
C++ classes with different definitions are not ABI compatible. In some very specific cases you can get away with it without a crash, but there are no guarantees and you should not expect it to work.
Furthermore, Protocol Buffers C++ library does not guarantee any ABI stability:

Protobuf C++ disclaims all cross-runtime support and requires an exact match between its generated code version and its runtime version at all times. Additionally, Protobuf C++ makes no guarantees about ABI stability across any releases (major, minor, or micro).


Thanks a lot. We found that replacing native malloc to jemalloc can solve the current problem, but your answer has given us a warning that there may be some issues when changing the proto version in the future.
